# docker-compose up build one image and don't launch the other

Tags: angular, docker

My stack is composed of :

- mariadb, existing image
- symfony, existing image
- angular, my own Dockerfile

If I launch mariadb and symfony without angular, they work well.

But if I add the frontend part to the docker-compose file, and launch `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose build`, the frontend is built first, and stopped at `compiled successfully` and I can't figure out why.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
COPY . ./
RUN ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Here is the docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/symfony:1'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_PROJECT_NAME=backend
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306 
      - MARIADB_USER=monty
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=ecommerce
    user: "1000"
    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - ${FRONTEND_PORT}:${FRONTEND_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/usr/src/app/
    container_name: frontend
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/bitnami/mariadb:rw
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=ecommerce
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
      - MARIADB_USER=monty
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=monty
    user: "1000"
    container_name: mariadb
```

And here is the end of the stack trace :

```
Creating network "web_ecommerce_2019_default" with the default driver
Building frontend
Step 1/9 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 003358826bdb
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b80128411a06
Step 3/9 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in a4ad3ef0c8a0
Removing intermediate container a4ad3ef0c8a0
 ---> 78a0d6ebe0aa
Step 4/9 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 904c4a0bc568
Removing intermediate container 904c4a0bc568
 ---> bbf5724bc6ed
Step 5/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> b42de2577a71
Step 6/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in cf82a0a54928

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> @angular/cli@9.0.7 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1355 packages from 1121 contributors and audited 1360 packages in 35.503s

44 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 5 vulnerabilities (3 low, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container cf82a0a54928
 ---> 66a77c23391d
Step 7/9 : RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
 ---> Running in f3faf59bdf90
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.0.4: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 
(node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@7.3.9
added 290 packages from 180 contributors in 13.394s
 Removing intermediate container f3faf59bdf90
 ---> 13a82ea9872f
Step 8/9 : COPY . ./
 ---> 4a60b6662c58
Step 9/9 : RUN ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
 ---> Running in 7ece55d37214
WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 60.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.69 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.99 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-09-21T09:49:21.249Z - Hash: a0c3616136a93ab0d917 - Time: 29924ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on 
http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.

Date: 2020-09-21T09:49:22.371Z - Hash: a0c3616136a93ab0d917
5 unchanged chunks

Time: 806ms
: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: I guess you could change "ng serve" from a RUN to a CMD, meaning that this becomes the default command when "running" the image instead of "building" the image. Like CMD ["ng","serve","--host", "0.0.0.0"] - otherwise I imagine this is a running task and the "building" of the image is never finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile: `RUN` defines a command to be run at build time. You define commands to be run in the container (based on the image) with `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.

Replace the last RUN command with: `CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`